# Derby database to sql script

Tags: derby

Is it possible to get a structure of a derby database so it is saved in a form of an sql script that I can run and it would recreate the database along with the data in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dblook tool (http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/tools/ctoolsdblook.html) will get the structure of the database and export it as a SQL script.

But it doesn't extract the data.

You could perhaps use the backup and restore utilities, but the format of a Derby backup is not a sql script.

The Apache 'ddlutils' tool can extract and move the data, I believe. See: http://db.apache.org/derby/integrate/db_ddlutils.html
and
http://db.apache.org/ddlutils/